# Is it possible to run OS X Lion inside a virtual machine in Windows 7 Bootcamp on Mac hardware?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, osx-lion, boot-camp

All of the answers I've come across seem to either pre-date the change in the OS X EULA or are not dealing with real Apple hardware.  The reason I want to do this is because I love my Macbook Air, I build iOS apps, but my bread and butter is in developing .Net applications.  I currently run Lion and build my .Net apps in a Win7 virtual machine, but it's not ideal.  I'm not interested in running a half-baked, legally-questionable solution.  I want to know if it will actually work from a tool like VMWare Player without spending the hours needed to try it out on my laptop for real.  Anybody tried this?

Comment: It's still violating the EULA, since the Mac computer won't be already running OS X. [See the quote in this answer on Meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2792/how-should-we-act-upon-install-os-x-as-virtual-machine-questions/2865#2865) ("the Apple software" refers to OS X).

Answer (score 0):

A "questionable" solution patches some of the hardware checks that forbid the VM from starting.  I don't think you're going to have a lot of success using Lion out of the box inside a VM, regardless of the underlying hardware.  The VM software will have different virtual hardware IDs than the real Mac hardware.  Haven't tried it myself, but this is my understanding.